# 'Get-AzPostgreSqlFirewallRule' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to get the firewall rules of an Azure postgressql database however I get this error:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Set-AzContext -Subscription "sub-mysubscription-dev"
Get-AzPostgreSqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "rg-myresourcegroup-dev" -ServerName "psql-mydb-dev"
```

Result:

```
Name                                     Account                                                          SubscriptionName                                                 Environment                                                      TenantId

sub-mysubscription-dev (myid x@y                                        
sub-mysubscription-dev                                                  
AzureCloud                                                       
Get-AzPostgreSqlFirewallRule: C:\Users\....\test.ps1:5:1
Line |
5 |  Get-AzPostgreSqlFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "rg- myresourcegroup-dev" -Se …
 |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 | The term 'Get-AzPostgreSqlFirewallRule' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I have already connected to Azure and sat up subscription.

I have also installed cmdlet module after facing this error but it didn't fix the issue:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

I am wondering what it is missing here

###Updated:
The same error using Connect-AzAccount command as well.

Comment: use `Connect-AzAccount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You should use the `Connect-AzAccount` command to connect to your Azure account.

2.[Install](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.PostgreSql/0.1.0) the `Az.PostgreSql` module.

Comment: I have already connected and sat up subscription.

Comment: @Matrix  Are you sure you  using `Connect-AzAccount` instead of `Connect-AzureAD` command?

Comment: @Matrix  Do not confuse these two commands.

Comment: I have tried the command that you mentioned but I get the same error.

Comment: @Matrix  Wait a minute, let me test

Comment: ok, just for info I am running this on windows 10, in visualstadiocode ,  PowerShell Integrated Console v2021.5.1

Comment: @Matrix  After my test, you should be missing the `Az.PostgreSql` module. Install the module and try it.   https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.PostgreSql/0.1.0

Comment: @Matrix I edited the answer, can you accept it as an answer? Thanks.